# Input type checkbox is not showing up on heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku-postgres

I'm having problems with a deployment on Heroku. I'm using rails 4 and postgresql.

The following code works fine in my local version, but doesn't appear AT ALL in the deployed version. All other features in my app work as they should.

In my new.html.erb file:

`<input type="checkbox" id=<%= i.id %>  onclick="addItem(<%= i.id %>)" />`

When I inspect element in the browser, there's not even a trace of it. Any clues as to what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your git repository status. Is your code committed correctly?
Your working directory and git code should be the same. Or do checkout or check your code again.

Or check code of that file using

```
$ heroku run bash --app appname

$ cat pathofyourfile
```

Then list your files and check code there is correct or not....

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I was using CSS Opacity.